# HP G8 trays keep on showing disk activity when there should be none

Tags: hard-drive, centos7, hp-proliant

I have a DL380 G8 with a P420i raid controller.  2 RAID1 logical drives have been setup - one containing the OS (CentOS7) and one made of a single almost empty partition (contains a single tiny text file - it is a test machine at the moment).

The HP trays are meant to show activity, failures, etc. The OS logical drive trays do act seemingly normally (sometimes show activity, sometimes don't), but that second logical drive shows constant activity (the "ring LEDs" keep on moving around) even though there is no real reason for it to show activity as it contains a text file that no process is using at any time.

A few "failure tests" (removing a disk while running) show that otherwise the trays work correctly in showing a degraded array, etc.

The question is simply : what's going on?

Comment: How long has it been doing that? What file system are you using and how big is it? Ext4 for instance performs lazy initialization when you first create it. This can last a while, because it doesn't do it at full speed.

Comment: It had been done not long ago (15 minutes) as I wrote that question. I ended up rebooting and that stopped happening, but I still wanted an explanation. I was in fact using Ext4. Can you point me to a filesystem that would not do this, for testing purposes?

Comment: *”removing a disk while running)”* - that should trigger a background array rebuild and regardless of the amount of actual data on the array the whole disk will need to be re-initialized to become part of the array which is a background process that does take time and won’t complete immediately - you have too much time on hand if you can spend it watching blinking lights ;)

Comment: HBruijn - The "drive removal" was not relevant to the question, but was mentioned  to  make note that the tray seemed to be working in that they showed array rebuilds/"do not remove" leds.  I understand the rebuild will create disk activity.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed indeed to simply be a file system initializing over a long period.

(Not sure how to give Halfgaar props for this as he has a comment, not an answer)